# How to run instrumentation tests using fastlane in emulator?

Tags: android, testing, fastlane, android-instrumentation

The problem that I face is I couldn't run the espresso tests using FastLane, what I want to do is run the tests in an emulator by Fastlane plugin

I used automated_test_emulator_run plugin of Fastlane, I follow the steps in this article  https://medium.com/pink-room-club/android-continuous-integration-using-fastlane-and-circleci-2-0-part-i-7204e2e7b8b

for now, I just want to run the tests locally so when I run the following

bundle exec Fastlane instrumentation_tests

it fails with error: No such file or directory - /tools/bin/avdmanager

here my lane in Fastlane

```
default_platform(:android)

platform :android do
desc "Runs all the tests"
lane :test do
gradle(task: "test")
end

#for increment the version code
android_get_version_code(
gradle_file: "app/build.gradle" # optional
)

android_set_version_code(
gradle_file: "app/build.gradle" # optional
)

desc "Run instrumentation tests"
lane :instrumentation_tests do
automated_test_emulator_run(
AVD_setup_path: "fastlane/AVD_setup.json",
AVD_recreate_new: false,
AVD_clean_after: false,
gradle_task: "connectedDebugAndroidTest")
end
end
```

And this my AVD_setup.json

```
{
"avd_list": [
  {
    "avd_name": "Pixel_2_API_Test",

    "create_avd_package": "system-images;android-28;google_apis_playstore;x86",
    "create_avd_device": "Pixel 2",
    "create_avd_tag": "google_apis_playstore",
    "create_avd_abi": "x86",
    "create_avd_additional_options": "",
    "create_avd_hardware_config_filepath": "",

    "launch_avd_port": "",
    "launch_avd_snapshot_filepath": "",
    "launch_avd_launch_binary_name": "emulator",
    "launch_avd_additional_options": "-skin 1080x1920 -gpu on"
  }
]
}
```

here is a part of the output and the error I got

```
[13:34:31]: Driving the lane 'android instrumentation_tests' 
[13:34:31]: -----------------------------------------
[13:34:31]: --- Step: automated_test_emulator_run ---
[13:34:31]: -----------------------------------------
[13:34:31]: The automated_test_emulator_run plugin is working!
[13:34:31]: Preparing commands for Android ADB
[13:34:31]: Preparing parameters and commands for emulator: 
Pixel_2_API_Test
[13:34:31]: Configuring environment in order to launch emulators: 
[13:34:31]: Getting avaliable AVDs
[13:34:31]: $ /tools/bin/avdmanager list avd
+--------------------------+-------------------------------+
|                       Lane Context                       |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------+
| DEFAULT_PLATFORM         | android                       |
| ANDROID_VERSION_CODE     | 38                            |
| ANDROID_NEW_VERSION_CODE | 39                            |
| PLATFORM_NAME            | android                       |
| LANE_NAME                | android instrumentation_tests |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------+
[13:34:31]: No such file or directory - /tools/bin/avdmanager

+------+-----------------------------+-------------+
|                 fastlane summary                 |
+------+-----------------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action                      | Time (in s) |
+------+-----------------------------+-------------+
| 1    | default_platform            | 0           |
| 2    | android_get_version_code    | 0           |
| 3    | android_set_version_code    | 0           |
| 4    | prompt                      | 4           |
|    | automated_test_emulator_run | 0           |
+------+-----------------------------+-------------+

[13:34:31]: fastlane finished with errors

[13:34:31]: Error accessing file, this might be due to fastlane's 
directory handling
[13:34:31]: Check out 
https://docs.fastlane.tools/advanced/#directory-behavior for more 
details
```

> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open3.rb:199:in `spawn': No such file or directory - /tools/bin/avdmanager (Errno::ENOENT)
>           from
>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open3.rb:199:in `popen_run'
>           from
>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open3.rb:190:in `popen2e'
>           from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane->2.120.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/helper/sh_helper.rb:54:in`sh_control_output'
>           from >/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/forwardable.rb:202:in `sh'
>           from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-plugin-automated_test_emulator_run-1.6.0/lib/fastlane/plugin/automated_test_emulator_run/actions/automated_test_emulator_run_action.rb:48:in`run'
>           from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.120.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:256:in `block (2 levels) in execute_action'
>           from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane- 
>       2.120.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/actions/actions_helper.rb:50:in`execute_action'
>           from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.120.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:235:in `block in execute_action'
>           from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.120.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:227:in`chdir'
>           from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.120.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:227:in `execute_action'
>           from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.120.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:157:in`trigger_action_by_name'
>           from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.120.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/fast_file.rb:154:in `method_missing'
>           from Fastfile:26:in`block (2 levels) in parsing_binding'
>           from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.120.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane.rb:33:in `call'
>           from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.120.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:49:in`block in execute'
>           from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.120.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:45:in `chdir'
>           from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.120.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:45:in`execute'
>           from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.120.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane_manager.rb:56:in `cruise_lane'
>           from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.120.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/command_line_handler.rb:36:in`handle'
>           from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.120.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in run'

I don't know what should I do? what I missed? the error mention that this might be due to fastlane's directory handling so I went to the link but didn't understand what to do?! I am using updated fastlane and plugins, please help me and thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignore the standard fastlane error message regarding directory handling.

This is a thing between the plugin you are using (https://github.com/AzimoLabs/fastlane-plugin-automated-test-emulator-run from my googling - you didn't actually provide more information about that), the command/program it tries to use (`/tools/bin/avdmanager list avd`) and your local Android installation.

You should find out if your local Android actually has the `avdmanager` command and where it lives, and if `list avd` works with it. Then find out why the plugin is not using it from the correct location.

A hunch: Might be the plugin is using an ENV variable `ANDROID_HOME` or similar that is empty on your system.

Comment: Ha, awesome! You could create an issue for the plugin, so that it outputs an error message if the ENV variable is missing or empty.